# Replace Apple Mapkit with Google Maps for business or work

Tags: google-maps, mapkit

How to migrate from **Apples MapKit** to google maps for business or work

For example How to know the relevant class for MKAnnotation - MapKit in Google Maps for business

Comment: For what platform are developing for? Web, iOS, Android? Check out google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 1):

Some of the classes of Google Maps similar to that found in Mapkit are:

1. GMSMapView ~ MKMapView
2. GMSMarker ~ MKAnnotation
3. GMSMapViewDelegate ~ MKMapViewDelegate
4. GMSPolyline ~ MKPolyline

Complete guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/